# Read csv file in python for only last 10 years

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on stock market data set. I am reading Apple stock data. In the csv I have 22 years of data, but I only want to read 10 years of data. In Date column, the date starts with 1999-12-31 and latest date is 2022-10-28. How should I do it.

I have to read 100 stock data using for loop. This is the code I used

```
df = []
for i in range(0,102): 
    df.append(pd.read_csv(file_name[i]+'.csv'))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAatx.png)

Here, after running this, df[0] is showing Apple stock data, df[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAatx.png) showing another stock and so on....
The code is working fine. But I am reading data for last 20 years I only want last 10 years.
Also every stock has different dates. Some have only 5 years data. That's ok I don't want more than 10 yrs back data. Less than 10 will work.
Also, I have to read 100 csv file using for loop.
Can anyone suggest me code for this.

Comment: `read_csv` doesn't filter the data. The only way to filter rows, `skiprows`, works with the row indexes, not their values. You'll have to load the files first, then filter them. If you want to filter while loading you need a different library, eg polars

Comment: `df.append(pd.read_csv(file_name[i]+'.csv'))` is pretty slow too, as each `append` operation creates a new, ever bigger dataframe. It's better to load all the dataframes and call `concat`, eg `pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file_name[i]+'.csv') for i in range(0,102)])`. You could even filter the individual dataframes this way.

Answer (score 0):

In CSV it does not skip the data.range function is there for selecting the data for the required.

Comment: So, I have to read all data then select only the desired part. Right ?